# Need subquery for conditional output

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I am working with a set of vehicle data that uses the following query:

```
SELECT 
    VIN_NUM AS [Registration VIN]
    ,REGION_IND AS [Location of Registration]
    ,REG_CHANGE AS [Changed Location Since Last Check]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN REG_CHANGE = '' THEN REGION_IND 
        ELSE REG_CHANGE 
    END AS [Final Location]
FROM
    dbo.All_Tests
WHERE
VIN_NUM LIKE '1FM%' AND
CASE 
    WHEN REGION_IND = '1' THEN 'Upstate'
    WHEN REGION_IND = '2' THEN 'Downstate'
    ELSE 'Unknown' 
END = 'Downstate'
```

The query pulls from a table a vehicle VIN (VIN_NUM) and whether it is located in one of two regions (REGION_IND), "1" or "2". It also pulls a column, "REG_CHANGE" checking if the vehicle registration has changed location between the two regions since last report. All three come from the same table.

REG_CHANGE is blank (not NULL) if there was no change, and contains the new region location, '1' or '2', if there was a change. This is used in a CASE statement with REGION_IND to give a current location to all vehicles in the database, alias name [Final Location].

The code works if I want the original regions since REGION_IND is a table column. However, I can't use [Final Location] because WHERE statements don't allow aliases. I'm thinking this would be a subquery construct within the SELECT columns, but I'm not certain how it would be structured.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful approach for this is to use an `apply`operator within the `from`clause which then does permit the use of that column alias within the where clause:

```
SELECT
    VIN_NUM    AS [registration vin]
  , REGION_IND AS [location of registration]
  , REG_CHANGE AS [changed location since last check]
  , ca.[final location]
FROM dbo.All_Tests
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN REG_CHANGE = '' THEN REGION_IND
            ELSE REG_CHANGE
        END AS [final location]
    ) ca
WHERE VIN_NUM LIKE '1FM%'
AND ca.[final location] = 'Downstate'
```

Any further uses of `àpply` that follow can also use these column aliases.

btw: Although a SQL select query starts with the select clause, that clause performed after the from and where clauses. So defining a column alias in the from clause makes that alias available much earlier in the execution of the query.

Answer (score 0):

you can write your where like below

```
   SELECT 
            VIN_NUM AS [Registration VIN]
            ,REGION_IND AS [Location of Registration]
            ,REG_CHANGE AS [Changed Location Since Last Check]
            ,CASE 
                WHEN REG_CHANGE = '' THEN REGION_IND 
                ELSE REG_CHANGE 
            END AS [Final Location]
        FROM
            dbo.All_Tests
        WHERE
        VIN_NUM LIKE '1FM%' AND
        (
            (REGION_IND = '1' and REG_CHANGE ='Upstate') OR
            (REGION_IND = '2' and REG_CHANGE ='Downstate') OR                
            (REG_CHANGE = 'Downstate')
       )
```